# TabBarItem Icon is not set in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

in my `UIViewController` I have the following method:

```
-(void)setTabBarIcon{
    AppDelegate * appDel = [[AppDelegate alloc]init];
    UIImage *activeIcon = [appDel makeTabBarImageFromMyFaceWithOptionalRed:YES];
    UIImage *inactiveIcon = [appDel makeTabBarImageFromMyFaceWithOptionalRed:NO];
    activeIcon = [activeIcon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    inactiveIcon = [inactiveIcon imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Jij" image:inactiveIcon selectedImage:activeIcon];
}
```

It changes the image of the tabBarItem associated with my ViewController.

Now, on startup of the App, I also need set that image. Since required information is not yet available, I do something similar in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions2:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UITabBarController *tabb = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    UITabBarItem *myFace = [tabb.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    //myFace.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"beam.png"];
    UIImage *placeholder = [UIImage imageNamed:@"beam.png"];
    myFace = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Bla" image:placeholder selectedImage:placeholder];

    return YES;
}
```

Two observations:

1. The line `*myFace = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:*` doesn't do anything, at least not visible to me.
2. When I uncomment the line `*myFace.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"beam.png"];*` an image actually is displayed.
3. Once that image is displayed, the first method is not changing the image of the `TabBarItem` anymore, when called.

I guess I'm addressing different instances of a `TabBarItem`, or something, but I'm completely puzzled and I hope one of you can see where I'm going wrong.

**EDIT:**
It might be of potential importance to note that my `UIViewController` is embedded in a UINavigationController. So, the Hierarchy is:

**UITabbarController>UINavigationController>UIViewController**. The latter is from where I successfully set the TabBar's image with *-(void)setTabBarIcon*

Thanks in advance for your advise.

Comment: Hi, have you tried in setTabBarIcon use   [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]]; &  [self.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Title"];  instead of initialization?

Comment: That could be a workaround, that I could fall back to, but I would lose the selected/unselected image properties.

Comment: You can set it there too:  [self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"]]; Or did I get your comment wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. It really seems that the AppDelegate is talking to another instance, but I don't know why. I updated my question with a Hierarchy. Maybe that is of importance.

Comment: What about to access to taBarItem in setTabBarIcon this way:  self.navigationController.tabBarItem ?

Comment: You might be onto something. I see some odd behavior, but is seems to be the right direction. I'll get back to you.